# Нужно помочь в написании лёгкой Python программе

Tags: python, python-3.x

Задайте с клавиатуры 7 любых неповторяющихся чисел. сформируйте список содержащий введенные числа выведите на экран все возможные комбинации пар чисел/

сложить все четные значения кратные 3 в диапазоне от 1 до 200 вывести полученный результат на экран/

Comment: Алексей, вам стоит разбираться сначала самому, затем предоставить пример вашего решения и объяснить, что не получилось. Написать за вас != помочь

Answer (score 1):

## Задача 1

```python
list = []  # Создаем пустой список
for _ in range(7):  # Семь раз добавляем в список введенные значения
    list += [input()]

for i in list:  # Проходимся по всем элементам списка переменной i, которая будет принимать значения из этого списка
    for j in list:  # Второй раз проходимся по этому же списку, но на этот раз другой переменной
        print(i, j)  # Выводим комбинацию i и j
```

## Задача 2

```python
summ = 0  # Задаем сумму 0

for i in range(1, 201): # Проходимся по всем значениям от 1 до 201 (201 не включая)
    if i % 6 == 0:  # Если остаток при делении i на 6 равен 0 (i четное b кратно 3), то ...
        summ += i # Прибавить i к нашей сумме

print(summ)
```

Answer (score 0):

Немного более продвинутый уровень... :)

### Задача 1

```
from itertools import product
print(list(product(*[[int(input()) for _ in range(7)]]*2)))
```

### Задача 2

```
print(sum(range((1+5)//6*6, (201+5)//6*6, 6)))
```